# I am having an error in Android studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvqID.png)I am new to android. I just created a project in android studio and having problem in its `manifest.xml`.  The error is in

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher
```

it is not able to resolve this symbol. 
I am on android studio 1.2.11

Comment: could you please post your manifest file too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher
```

with

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

That is, your manifest should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.org.yourpackage" >
    <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".YourStartingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**

Try,

```
Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart
```

in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks,  but it didn't work for me. My drawable folder doesn't have any file in it. I tried to copy and paste images from mipmap folder this didn't work either.

Comment: My manifest is same as above. but when I change mipmap to  drawable .it shows the same error i.e cannot resolve the symbol drawable. one thing to metion-my res/drawable folder is empty

Comment: May be you have some other errors in your xml file..try to clean and build the app..

Comment: I restarted and rebuilt  a project with predetermined blank activity  by studio . i didnt touch a single line of code  got the same error.

Comment: is it showing a red underline below `android:icon`? is that the error?

Comment: before trying all others, please try this  `Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart.`

Comment: Great..:) Glad that it helped.. @AkashKhandelwal..Could you please mark the answer as accepted if it really helped you..

Answer (score 0):

Look in the mipmap folder and see if the launcher icon is in there for the right resolution you are using . You can change it to "@/ic_launcher" where the folder is where your icon is.

Answer (score 0):

The mipmap folders are for placing your app icons in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

According to this [Google blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html):

It’s best practice to place your launcher icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.
When referencing the mipmap- folders ensure you are using the following reference:

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Add your launcher icons to mip map folder